# Relationships between complexity theory and software engineering?

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm interested to know if there is any literature out there on the relationship of complexity theory (emergence, complex systems, evolution) and software development processes. I read somewhere that SCRUM philosophy came out of the theory of punctuated equilibrium in evolution theory. Are there any additional studies/researches on this subject?

Thanks!

Comment: How does this involve programming? And agile seems to be heavily influenced by W.E. Deming writings, btw, just as design patterns was influenced by Christopher Alexander.

Comment: For me it, it's more like `chaos theory` ;-)

Comment: "complexity theory" is probably not the right thing to call the topic you're talking about, at least without qualification.  "complexity theory" in computer circles is already taken by another topic: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slightly tongue-in-cheek book called [Systemantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemantics). Because a software program is a type of system, its observations are applicable to software: for example,

- The bigger the system, the narrower and more specialized the interface with individuals.
- A complex system cannot be "made" to work. It either works or it doesn't.
- A simple system, designed from scratch, sometimes works.
- Some complex systems actually work.
- A complex system that works is invariably found to have evolved from a simple system that works.
- A complex system designed from scratch never works and cannot be patched up to make it work. You have to start over, beginning with a working simple system.

Answer (score 1):

There interesting blog posts by Jurgen Appelo of [NOOP.NL](http://www.noop.nl) fame, which are related to application of complexity theory to software engineering and project management:

- [Your Project Will Suffer From Power Laws](http://www.noop.nl/2009/07/your-project-will-suffer-from-power-laws.html)
- [What (Else) Can Agile Learn from Complexity?](http://www.noop.nl/2009/08/what-else-can-agile-learn-from-complexity-presentation.html)

These can be helpful in researching this topic.